# Using JPA specification with custom sql query

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, filter

I have below code to filter the data with given criteria:

```
public Page<Entity_DTO> findByCriteria(Entity_Criteria criteria, Pageable page) {

final Specification<Entity> specification = createSpecification(criteria);

return Page<Entity_DTO> Entity_DTOPage =
    Entity_Repo.findAll(specification, page).map(Entity_DTO_Mapper::toDTO);
}
```

`createSpecification` creates a JPA Specification based on the criteria. Now i want to add another filter, but the problem is that filter can't be added to `createSpecification` because i don't have a repository class for that filter as the filter is stored in a table which is managed by external library. So i can't create an `Entity` and `Repository` class for that filter. But i have access to that table using custom sql queries. So i want to know if there's a way to add a custom query(more specifically `WHERE`) alongside the `specification` variable created using `createSpecification` to return the filtered data. Or do i need to do away with the `specification` and perform filtering solely using queries? Current filters are like `health, size etc.` and i want to add another filter say `status`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't mix a @Query definition with a Specification, so currently it's not possible to combine custom sql queries with specifications